# i set in docker-compose "127.0.0.101:80:80" and why gataway and ip adres i get from another subnet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ip, port

## **i set in docker-compose "127.0.0.101:80:80"

## and why gataway and ip adres i get from another subnet**

**"Gateway": "172.31.0.1",**
**"IPAddress": "172.31.0.2",**

**i create docker container with docker-file:**

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        hostname: project1
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.101:80:80"
        networks:
            some_network:
                aliases:
                    - project1.local
                    - www.project1.local

networks:
    some_network:
        # Общая сеть со смежными проектами
        name: 'our_network'
```

**make **

```
**docker container inspect 50631755223c**
```

**im get**

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "53e14814f2bd19036439e5327a91416784920841435195d362c751d9995de5b5",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        **"HostIp": "127.0.0.101",**
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/53e14814f2bd",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "our_network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {},
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "pr1-web-1",
                        "web",
                        "project1.local",
                        "www.project1.local",
                        "50631755223c",
                        "project1"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "9610c4d18d33068427f3eb4d5c3ecce87da5afc9eef59f610757f10a98156915",
                    "EndpointID": "1d60133501de2edc51f45db05ba0727ced4d2a102d63a8e26a3d9a2f93567d04",
                    "Gateway": **"172.31.0.1",**
                    "IPAddress": **"172.31.0.2",**
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1f:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
```

## **i set in docker-compose "127.0.0.101:80:80"

## and why gataway and ip adres i get from another subnet**

**"Gateway": "172.31.0.1",**
**"IPAddress": "172.31.0.2",**

I was expecting the gataway to be from the same subnet as I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker inspect` dumps out very low-level diagnostic information about your container.  You almost never need any of the information there.  More specifically, the IP-related information it prints out is all but useless.

There are two layers of Docker networking.  Each container internally does happen to have its own IP address, and there is an IP network corresponding to the Docker network (in your example, the manually-configured `some_network` network).  Docker's assigned that network the IPv4 address range 172.31.0.0/16.  Again, this is an implementation detail you don't need to know about.

Separately from this, you've requested to publish `ports:` from the container to the host.  `ports: ['127.0.0.101:80:80']` says, in order, that on the host interface bound to the address `127.0.0.101`, forward port 80 to port 80 inside the container.  This is visible in the `docker inspect` output (under `ports:`), but that IP address is the *host's* IP address and not part of the Docker-internal networking space.

To reiterate, in practice none of this matters.  I'd use the normal localhost IP address 127.0.0.1 as the bind address if you want a container port to be accessible from outside a container on the same host but not from other hosts, and I'd use the `default` network Compose provides for you.  I'd reduce the Compose setup to just

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
```

(removing all of the `networks:` blocks, the `hostname:` setting, and fixing the host IP address in `ports:`)

and ignore the `docker inspect` output entirely.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find this information in the official docker documentation. I have a docker server on my home network. The router distributes a static IP address to the server. I want my containers to have access to each other. Ideally, my containers would be in the router's network in which the server itself is located. This can be done? If yes, please tell me how? I've been trying to resolve this issue for 3 days now. Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: My router network is 192.168.68.1.

Comment: Completely delete the host-IP part of `ports:`.  Your container will be served on port 80 in the same way as if the Nginx server was running directly on the host.

Comment: Perhaps I formulated the question incorrectly or translated the translator incorrectly. The question is:
We have a Home network with a router that distributes IP addresses via DHCP. The router has an IP address of 192.168.68.1. There are several home servers on the network, one of them with the address 192.168.168.120, it is statically assigned. I want my Docker containers to be able to assign IP addresses on the router network: 192.168.68.121, 192.168.68.122 and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: I'd probably do that the same way I'd do it without Docker, assign the additional IP addresses to virtual interfaces on the host, and then you could use the IP-address part of `ports:` to bind to one of those specific interfaces.